# Format string and return as anonymous type C#

Tags: c#

I have the folowing code

```
var details = GetDetails();
return details; //array of objects
```

This contains a proterty `details[0].LocationTime` which is of datatype DateTime. I need to format the date and return it as string using a utility method like `FormatDate(details[0].LocationTime)`. So the return object will have `details.LocationTime` as a string datatype and not DateTime.

How can I do this using anonymous types and LINQ. Without creating another class and using a for loop.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

```
var details = GetDetails();
return details.Select(d => new { LocationTime =  FormatDate(d.LocationTime) });
```

It works if your `FormatDate()` method returns string.

Comment: It makes no difference. Above method should work for you. Just @Mateusz Rogulski should change "detail.LocationTime" to "d.LocationTime" as:
return details.Select(d => new { LocationTime =  FormatDate(d.LocationTime) });